# mysql # of affected rows not informative

Tags: php, mysqli

A MySQL Update command will report zero rows affected if no rows match the conditions OR there is actually no change to the row that does match.

A user wants to edit their profile so I query the DB for the row `"WHERE UserID='$userid'"` and display a form with each column's value in a text field for him to edit.

On submit I execute an Update command and check the `mysqli_affected_rows` expecting `1` for success and `0` for failure. If he didn't actually change anything, it comes back `0` and I get a false error report.

I can think of a couple of cumbersome ways to avoid this, but I'm hoping someone has an easy solution?

Comment: You could add an updated_at field that's always updated. Fairly common too.

Comment: Don't notify user. Or add specific notification -> "You didn't change anything." and add updated_at field to check as Christopher suggested.

Comment: Yes, a LastUpdate column is the "cumbersome" approach I was thinking of. I just hate cluttering up the code and expanding the DB

Answer (score 1):

Returning zero affected rows is actually not an error - many things affect nothing while the actual SQL-query is still successful. When an actual error is reported by mysqli_affected_rows, it will return -1, not 0.

Also, if you want to catch actual errors, you might want to use mysqli_errno, or similar command instead - especially after mysqli_affected_rows returns -1.

I suggest you simply tell the user "OK"/"Thank you" or similar, and only inform in case of an actual error.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple.

Just get rid of this useless checking and simply tell the user that his data has been updated successfully.

Comment: It's highly unlikely anything could go wrong, but it seems a bit sloppy not to check.

Comment: @joseph4 you just have to realize that # of affected rows has nothing to do with something goes wrong. If you want to check, then you have to check whether something gone wrong, not the # of affected rows.

Comment: However, it makes your code a bit messy if you're going to check every single line in order to see whether it's gone wrong.